# While loop value test

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, testing, while-loop

I have an array of objects that contains a key value with true or false. These values start as false but switch to true on completion of their work. I was looking to determine when all the values had completed i.e. all switched to true.  Is there a deviation(logic below) on a while loop with a test if statement that may solve this.

```
basicarray = [{"value" : false}, {"value" : false},
              {"value" : false}, {"value" : false},
              {"value" : false}  ];
```

non working logic

---

```
totalcount = 0;

while(totalcount < basicarray.length )
{
  for(a=0 ; a < basicarray.length; a++)
  {
    if(basicarray[a].value = true)
    {
      totalcount = totalcount + 1;
    }
  }
}
alert("all true");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use == in place of = :

```
if(basicarray[a].value == true)  // Notice the ==
{
   totalcount++;    // this better than totalcount = totalcount + 1
}
```

Or

```
if(basicarray[a].value)
{
   totalcount++
}
```

Comment: Better to use `===` if you know the type.

Comment: You've missed the bigger error of infinite recursion if an instance of `basicarray[a].value != true`

Comment: @Justin - Where do you see recursion?

Comment: The OP has `while(totalcount < basicarray.length ) { for(a=0 ; a < basicarray.length; a++) { ... } }` If `totalcount` doesn't get incremented inside for every element of `basicaarray`, the `while` loop will never exit.

Comment: Oh missed that completely. Your soln is neat.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically just doing a `each` from the functional paradigm.  The following is equivalent:

```
var result = true;

for ( var i=0, l=basicarray.length; i<l; i++ ) {
    result = basicarray[i].value;

    // If result is ever false, there's no point in continuing
    if ( !result ) { break; }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why do `result = result && basicarray[i].value;`? Just `result = basicarray[i].value;` is okay.

Comment: You're right.  I originally had just that before I added the break, which makes it superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

This will count the array elements at start and then subtract from the counter when an element is true. Once the counter is zero all elements should be true.

```
  var basicarray = [{"value" : true}, {"value" : true},
                {"value" : true}, {"value" : true},
                {"value" : true}  ];

  var c = basicarray.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < basicarray.length; i++) {
    if(basicarray[i].value) c--;
  }

  if(c == 0) {
    alert('All True');
  }
```

Comment: You should use a normal `for` loop when iterating over arrays and `for..in` when iterating over object properties.  Also, regardless of convention, you should always program defensively when using a `for..in` loop (e.g., you should always check the `hasOwnProperty` method).

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct. Not sure why I used `for..in` statement. I've now corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution.

```
for (j in basicarray) {
   if (!basicarray[j].value) {break;}
   else {
      if (basicarray.length-1 == j) {
       alert("all complete");
      }
   }
}
```